# Does Geofire works with cloud firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, geofire, geofirestore

I'm building a rideshare android app, and would be making use of Firebase and Geofire.
I want to know if Geofire works with Cloud Firestore or just the realtime database.

Tried looking out for the answer online but get very vague answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has a set of geo-utility libraries and guides to describe how to use them to implement simple geo queries.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries

The Android section will help you use Geohashes to get geo querying functionality.

Good Luck!